# Lucene syntax: what is the difference between AND and +

Tags: search, lucene

I am newest in Lucene.
I'm using *Lucene.NET version 2.9.4*.

What is the difference between these queries?

the first is:

```
title:hello AND tags:word
```

the second is:

```
+title:hello +tags:word
```

I testing a software, and I note that the first returns 3 records, and the second returns many records.
I observe that the first returns records where `title` and `tags` fields are fuel, but the second returns records where `title` and `tags` can be empty.
Is it the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the two.  `clause1 AND clause2` is effectively shorthand for `+clause1 +clause2`

Similarly: `clause1 clause2` = `clause1 OR clause2`

Note, there is really no equivalent for `+clause1 clause2` using the boolean operators.

Comment: Thanks. I testing a software, and I note that the first returns 3 records, and the second returns many records. I observe that the first returns records where `title` and `tags` fields are fuel, but the second returns records where `title` and `tags` can be empty... Is it the difference?

Comment: No, the standard query parser should not return documents in which either of the fields are empty for either of those queries.  Are you using the standard query parser?  Or perhaps you have some custom functionality defined which transforms the query string before passing it to the query parser?

Comment: I understand. I don't know the response. Maybe I using Lucene.NET through Examine of Umbraco CMS... I will other tests.

Comment: Yes: I tested directly Lucene.NET. The 2 syntax produces the same results. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the query over the Internet, if you are and not urlencoding the request correctly it could be misinterting the '+' as an encoded space and therefore lucene just runs the second query as if the +'s not there which would just OR the two parts and give the results you get.

```
title:hello tags:word
```